# Get the file name and replace the file name with the value of the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get file name when user click on radio button and replace the file name with the value of radio button. I tried to get file name with the jquery but this wont work.

```
$('#activeImage').click(function(){
    var name = $('input[type=file]').prev("#productImg").val();
    alert(name);
})
```

This is the DOM structure.

```
<div class="controls">
     <input type="file" name="userfile[]" value="" id="productImg" style="border:0px;"  />                                     
     <input type="radio" name="activeImage" value="" id="activeImage"  />  
</div>
<div class="controls">
     <input type="file" name="userfile[]" value="" id="productImg" style="border:0px;"  />                                     
     <input type="radio" name="activeImage" value="" id="activeImage"  />  
</div>
```

How i get the file name and replace the file name with the value of the radio button

Comment: What do you mean "replace the file name" ?

Comment: an ID should be unique within the document. Do not reuse them. You cannot set the value of an `input type="file"` with javascript, if that's what you're attempting. The rest of your question and sample code is difficult to understand.

Comment: suppose user select a file for upload ( file name is mypic.jpg) and i just want to get file name (mypic) and insert this name in the vale="mypic" of radio button

Comment: actually the  2nd class="controls" is generated by the jquery clone method that's why it appears 2 times in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this to get the value of file field

```
$('#activeImage').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).prev('input[type=file]').val();
    alert(name);
});
```

You can rename the file only by using some programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
$('#activeImage').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).parents('.controls').find('input[type=file]').val();
    alert(name);
});
```